# Iterator into container which is moved

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

I've got a class which holds in it a container, and an iterator into that container. How can I correctly implement the move constructor? I seem to recall that by Standard, you can't rely on the iterators remaining valid after moving (which is so silly). Is there some means by which I can "update" the iterator if it was invalidated or something? Or will I have to dynamically allocate the container, move it, and then have the iterators remain valid that way?

Comment: Get the [distance](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) and [advance](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) the new iterator?

Comment: `you can't rely on the iterators remaining valid after moving (which is so silly)` Why is it "silly"?

Comment: Well you can use `swap`, not sure about moving: "no `swap()` function invalidates any references, pointers, or iterators referring to the elements of the containers being swapped. [*Note:* The `end()` iterator does not refer to any element, so it may be
invalidated. — *end note*]" [container.requirements.general]/10

Comment: Regarding the silly: It's not so silly when you think about `std::array`. There are other cases where the standard allows linear complexity for a move-constructor of a container, e.g. when the allocator changes. Another example might be containers which contain embedded first/last or root nodes.

Comment: I think there's an implicit guarantee that `move` doesn't invalidate iterators: "Unless otherwise specified (either explicitly or by defining a function in terms of other functions), invoking a
container member function or passing a container as an argument to a library function shall not invalidate iterators to, or change the values of, objects within that container." and Table 96 states only "post: `u` shall be equal to the value that `rv` had before this construction" for a move-construction `Container u(rv)`.

Comment: @DyP If I look at table 99 at `X(rv, m)`, it also allows copies of the elements. Logically, the iterators have to be invalidated. If we can't find wording to back this up, this should be a DR. (or maybe that is just one of the cases *not* included in what you wrote?)

Comment: @Daniel: You're right about `std::array`, but I have a question about this somewhere else on SO, and the Standard does not generally ban it. And as far as my use is concerned, the iterator marks a position into the container, and losing it if it's `end` is just as crippling a problem as losing it anywhere else.

Comment: @DanielFrey As the new elements are *copies* of the old elements in this case, the old elements can still exist and iterators to them can still be valid.

Comment: @DeadMG Updated my answer, but see for yourself as I think you should consider `std::unique_ptr` as a valid alternative.

Comment: @DyP The intend is to use them on the new container, not on the old one. In the context of the new container, they are then clearly invalid, just imagine `new_cont.erase( old_it );`.

Comment: @DanielFrey Of course they're not valid iterators to the new container, but you said "Logically, the iterators have to be invalidated." and that's not the case IMHO, even if the elements get copied.

Comment: Does it have to be *any* container?  Or do you have a specific container in mind?  Some containers are going to be more problematic than others.  But I think the different containers could have different but reasonable solutions.  For example I would handle `list` and `string` differently, but I think I could make a case for both of them.

Comment: I certainly need a general case for any container, but I'm not above special-casing some pre-defined containers if necessary- for example, `std::array`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I think it's "silly" in that move could fairly easily offer the same guarantees on iterator validity that `swap` does. But apparently it doesn't in general offer them.

Comment: @SteveJessop: `move` doesn't do anything but obtain an rvalue ref.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: typo, I meant "move", not "`move`". Fixed. Also, how did you decide which `std::move` I meant -- the one in `<utility>` that just obtains an rvalue, or the one in `<algorithm>` that performs 0 or more moves? ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop: Heard it all before... :P

Comment: @SteveJessop: Presumably _that_ `move` _does_ provide those same guarantees!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: well, if it does then DeadMG's recollection ("by Standard, you can't rely on the iterators remaining valid after moving") isn't quite correct, at least for containers that retain validity on `swap`, which is most or possibly all standard ones barring `array`. Then the correct answer to the question is "mu".

Comment: @SteveJessop: Well there we go then. Meanwhile, I only just spotted that this was DeadMG's question...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I suppose DeadMG can remark that it's silly that *none* of the containers guarantees it (if that's the case). Or even that it's silly the standard chose to make `array` a container.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I only really commented in the first place because I thought I was answering a low-rep user new to move semantics. In reality, I know very little about move semantics, other than that this `std::move` is tragically misnamed.

Comment: This issue is addressed by [LWG open issue 2321](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#2321).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** Using a `std::unique_ptr` as a holder for the container is the canonical generic solution - simply don't move the container, just transfer the ownership and swap the iterators. As you already said you can special-case this as an optimization, although I'd expect the generic solution to be also quite efficient and I'd only accept more complexity (aka bug-potential) to the code after proving that it's a real performance win for your use-case.

I'll leave the former answer below for future readers: Read it and the comments to see why other solutions are not really working and in which cases they cause trouble.

---

The obvious way to update the iterator would be:

```
Container c = ...;
Container::iterator it = ...;

const auto d = std::distance( c.begin(), it );
Container n = std::move(c);
it = n.begin();
std::advance( it, d );
```

which is generally linear, but constant when the iterator is a random access iterator.

Since you probably don't want to do that, you have two options which should help: Either default construct the new container and use `swap` without invalidating the iterators or put the container into a `std::unique_ptr` and move that instead.

The first approach (`swap`) requires both instances to have the container instance and this might be a bit larger than the simple, single pointer stored inside a `std::unique_ptr`. When you move your instances around very often, the `std::unique_ptr`-based approach seems preferable to me, although each access requires one more pointer indirection. Judge (and measure) for yourself what fits best in your case.

Comment: Or just `it = std::next(n.begin(), d)` for conciseness.

Comment: Owch, I think I'd rather pay dynamic allocation than a linear price.

Comment: @DeadMG Good choice :)

Comment: "use `swap` without invalidating the iterators" -- Do you happen to know what the standard says about this? Clearly even with `array` and a pointer as iterator, if you swap the containers then the iterator would be valid but still referring to the old array with its new contents. But (a) is it guaranteed? and (b) does the standard say anything in general about containers, or are you relying on the fact that each individual container in the standard retains iterator validity on swap? Could some third-party class be a `Container` but invalidate iterators on swap, or not?

Comment: Having the iterator be valid into the original container is useless to me.

Comment: @DeadMG: well, since you said you're happy to special-case `array` then you could swap the iterators as well as the containers in that case. Of course the problem is that since `std::array` is a valid container, so is `some_third_party::array`, and you can't special-case that. So I suspect it's formally impossible to base it on `swap` if you want to cover third-party containers as well as the standard ones. In that case you've already said your preferred option is dynamic allocation and indirection, job done.

Comment: (btw, I just confirmed that's how `std::array` iterators appear to behave on gcc, I'm still too lazy to check whether it's guaranteed since my copy of C++11 is in my other trousers).

Comment: Well, what I think right now is that I will use `unique_ptr` in general, but I can special-case say, all random-access containers, and use the `distance` technique for that. That should be a good start.

Comment: @SteveJessop You are right about `std::array` and probably other cases, updated my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Btw there are a lot of special cases for `std::array` in the Container specification. A non-standard container that behaves like `std::array` would probably not fulfil the Container requirements because it isn't `std::array` and therefore is not covered by these special cases.

Comment: Using `distance`&`advance`/`next` may not work for `std::unordered_set` - order of elements can be different.

Comment: `unordered_set` isn't random-access.

Comment: @EvgenyPanasyuk Right, there are even more problems with `distance`/`advance`, but that "solution" is bad anyways. `std::unique_ptr` is the only no-brainer that Just Works(tm) as it simply avoid all trouble by *not* moving the container.

Comment: @DeadMG `distance`&`advance` work for InputIterator.

Comment: @Evgeny: That's irrelevant to me. Only random-access offers the O(1) that would make such a solution a viable replacement.

Answer (score 1):

I think the implicit guarantee on iterator invalidation holds for the move ctor. That is, the following should work for all containers but `std::array`:

```
template<class Container>
struct foo_base
{
    Container c;
    Container::iterator i;

    foo_base(foo_base&& rhs, bool is_end)
    : c( std::move(rhs.c) )
    , i( get_init(is_end, rhs.i) )
    {}

    Container::iterator get_init(bool is_end, Container::iterator ri)
    {
        using std::end; // enable ADL
        return is_end ? end(c) : ri;
    }
};

template<class Container>
struct foo : private foo_base<Container>
{
    foo(foo&& rhs)
    : foo_base(std::move(rhs), rhs.i == end(rhs.c))
    {}
};
```

The complicated initialization via a base class is necessary as move assignment isn't required to move if the allocator doesn't propagate for move-assignment. The check for the iterator is required as the `end()` iterator may be invalidated; this check has to be performed before the container is moved. If you can ensure however that the allocator propagates (or otherwise the move-assignment doesn't invalidate iterators for your cases), you can use the simpler version below, replacing the `swap` with a move-assignment.

N.B. The sole purpose of the `get_init` function is to enable ADL. It is possible that `foo_base` has a member function `end`, which would disable ADL. The *using-declaration* stops unqualified lookup to find a possible member function, therefore ADL is always performed. You could as well use `std::end(c)` and get rid of `get_init`, if you're comfortable with losing ADL here.

If it should turn out that there is no such implicit guarantee for the move ctor, there's still the explicit guarantee for `swap`. For this, you can use:

```
template<class Container>
struct foo
{
    Container c;
    Container::iterator i;

    foo(foo&& rhs)
    {
        using std::end; // enable ADL
        bool const is_end = (rhs.i == end(rhs.c));

        c.swap( rhs.c );

        i = get_init(is_end, rhs.i);
    }

    Container::iterator get_init(bool is_end, Container::iterator ri)
    {
        using std::end; // enable ADL
        return is_end ? end(c) : ri;
    }
};
```

However, a swap has some requirements, defined in [container.requirements.general]/7+8:

> The behavior of a call to a container's `swap` function is undefined unless the objects being swapped have allocators that compare equal or `allocator_traits<allocator_type>::propagate_on_container_swap::value` is `true`
>   [...]
>   Any `Compare`, `Pred`, or `Hash` objects belonging to `a` and `b` shall be swappable and shall be exchanged by unqualified calls to non-member `swap`. If `allocator_traits<allocator_type>::propagate_on_container_swap::value` is `true`, then the allocators of `a` and `b` shall also be exchanged using an unqualified call to non-member `swap`. Otherwise, they shall not be swapped, and the behavior is undefined unless
>   `a.get_allocator() == b.get_allocator()`.

I.e. both containers should (but not have to) have equal allocators.

Move construction OTOH only requires that no exception is thrown (for allocator-aware containers); the allocator is always moved.

Comment: Well I'll add this here as a comment, too: There are a lot of special cases for `std::array` in the Container specification. A non-standard container that behaves like `std::array` would probably not fulfil the Container requirements because it isn't `std::array` and therefore is not covered by these special cases.